# How to implement MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

On a project we multiple Dialog's.
Now, I want to set samen global variables to the DialogOption.

I found: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview
and this code:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false}}
  ]
})
```

> I applied these code with some other, but it doesn't work. The
>   settings doesn't applied at all.

Does anybody get these setting worked?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That works... Go [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nnorporgbvx?file=main.ts) and add these to verify it.

```
import {MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material';

....

providers: [
  {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false}}
]
```

Comment: There is no `MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` in the link

Answer (score 27):

Angular Material provides practical defaults for several of its config options, such as `closeOnNavigation`, `autoFocus`, etc.

If you only want to overwrite a few of the config items, while leaving the rest as their defaults, you can provide `MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` like this:

```js
import {MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, MatDialogConfig} from '@angular/material';

...

  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: {
        ...new MatDialogConfig(),
        hasBackdrop: false,
      } as MatDialogConfig,
    }
  ]

...
```

With this approach, you only need to specify the config options you want to change. The rest will take their default values.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if someone still needs help, follow this pattern for mat dialog default options.

module.ts

```
{ provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
  useValue: { hasBackdrop: true, disableClose: true } as MatDialogConfig
}
```

Any Component where you want to open dialog.

```
const dialogConfig: MatDialogConfig = {}; // important to use this method.
dialogConfig.panelClass = 'no-padding-dialog';
// Any additional dialog configs
this.dialog.open(YourComponent, dialogConfig);
```

Avoid using following when you have to apply default configs as it create new instance of dialog config.

```
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig(); // Don`t use
```

Comment: Thanks! your remark about not creating a new config instance was super important.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Fartab, i saw my problem, the angular example opens te dialog at the following way:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  width: '250px',
  data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
});
```

But I'm open the dialog this way:

```
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.width = '600px';
dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
dialogConfig.data = {
  customer: data,
};
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteFtpCustomerComponent, dialogConfig);
```

I think every time I opend a dialog, the settings loaded from a new config.
So I changed the opening of the dialog to the example of Fartab. Now its workng :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import {
    MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS
  } from '@angular/material';

 @NgModule({
    providers: [  
        {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: 
        {hasBackdrop: true, direction: 'ltr',height:'500px'}}
    ]
 })
```

Adding like this  should affect default options,

examples values:

hasBackdrop:true // will not allow closing dialog when clicking outside of it.

direction: 'ltr' //sets where will text start - from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

We can disable angular material dialog box backdrop by setting  hasBackdrop and disableClose properties add inside the dialog option.

```
openDialog(tabIndex, paramIndex){
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TabChangeDialogboxComponent,{
  width: '330px',
  height: '200px',
  hasBackdrop: true, //Here line to add
  disableClose: true,//Here line to add
  data: {
    tabInd: tabIndex,
    paramInd: paramIndex 
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29790336)